# cannot fetch post data from android in php script

Tags: php, android, sql

I am trying to fetch some user fields from `android` to `php`

The `$mobile_num` is being populated correctly but other variables like `$user_name`, `$latitude`, `$longitude` are still empty.

```
<?php

include('ConnectDB.php');
$user_name=$_POST['userName'];
$mobile_num=$_POST['mobileNo'];
$latitude=$_POST['latitude'];
$longitude=$_POST['longitude'];
$status=1;

echo $mobile_num;

$sql = "INSERT INTO user (username,mobileNo,latitude,longitude,status ) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt>bind_param("sssss",$user_name,$mobile_num,$latitude,$longitude,$status);$result=$stmt->execute(); 


if($result)
    echo "inserted ". $result ." row/rows";
else
    die('Could not connect: ' . $con->error);

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

On hard coding the values, the code inserts the data correctly, but the post method is unable to catch values for username, latitude, longitude.

This is my android code:

```
 @Override
  protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    try {

        data= URLEncoder.encode("mobileNo","UTF-8")
                 + "="+URLEncoder.encode(mUser.getMobileNo(),"UTF-8");

        data+= URLEncoder.encode("userName","UTF-8")
                + "="+URLEncoder.encode(mUser.getUsername(),"UTF-8");

        data+= URLEncoder.encode("latitude","UTF-8")
                + "="+URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(mUser.getLatitude()),"UTF-8");

        data+= URLEncoder.encode("longitude","UTF-8")
                + "="+URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(mUser.getLongitude()),"UTF-8");

    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(activityContext, "ERROR: "+e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    return insertUserData(data);
}


private String insertUserData(String data)
{
    try
    {
        conn = DBConnection.createConnnection(php_file);
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        writer.write(data);
        writer.flush();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        response = reader.readLine();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;
}
```

What shall I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: can u elaborate on form ?

Comment: did you find a working solution yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you're creating your data string you need to put an '&' between each of your attributes. Do not url encode the '&'.

```
 data= URLEncoder.encode("mobileNo","UTF-8")
             + "="+URLEncoder.encode(mUser.getMobileNo(),"UTF-8");

    data+= "&" + URLEncoder.encode("userName","UTF-8")
            + "="+URLEncoder.encode(mUser.getUsername(),"UTF-8");

    data+= "&" + URLEncoder.encode("latitude","UTF-8")

            + "="+URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(mUser.getLatitude()),"UTF-8");

    data+= "&" + URLEncoder.encode("longitude","UTF-8")
            + "="+URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(mUser.getLongitude()),"UTF-8");
```